# Detecting the Delimiter in a String

Tags: c++, mfc

I was going though some C++ code, and came across this piece of code which I am unable to understand. Need your help for the same :

```
int intStart = strMessage.Find("\0019=%ld"); //strMessage is of type: CString and contains a message with delimiters
intStart++;
int intEnd = strMessage.Find("\00110=%ld");
intEnd++;
```

"\0019=%ld" and "\00110=%ld" are obviously some special characters or symbols which the code is trying to locate in the string: strMessage. I wanted to know which special character or symbol is being searched here? How to find it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\001` is the character with ASCII code 1.  The next digits `9` or `10` are just digits.

This may help

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

> which special character or symbol is being searched here?

The search is for the whole substring starting with that special character, followed by the rest of that quoted text.

Comment: Thanks. However if I am passing a string like:

Comment: Thanks. However if I am passing a string like: "1^9=0235^35=D^44=76.750000^59=0^10=165", my above code should return me the position starting from "9" in the above string (in the intStart  variable), and the position of last value - 165 in the intEnd variable. But both these variables is returning -1 here. Obviously '^' is not the delimiter here, that the code expects. So question is, what I am missing or doing wrong here?? And what should be the exact delimiter in my string, for this code to succeed. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the delimiter.  Also, I think what you are trying to do with `%ld` is wrong.  I don't think `Find` does any smart matching as you seem to expect.  It looks for an exact literal match.  `%ld` would match exactly those characters, not be a generic match for something of that format.

Comment: That's exactly where my confusion is. As you have rightly said - "find" looks for an exact literal match. So in that case the code - strMessage.Find("\0019=%ld") is wrong here, because we are unable to understand what it is trying to match here? Would you agree?

Comment: I still don't know what aspect of this is confusing you.  When you say "we are unable to understand", I don't know what aspect **you** don't understand.  The `\001` is one character and is the first character of the string being searched.  `9` is the second character, etc.  Your comment implied you thought it should return the position where it finds the `9`, but it never would, because it would return the position of the **first** character and only where it finds the whole substring.

Comment: You could change the `^` in strMessage to be `\001` to match what you are looking for, or you could change the `\001` in what you are looking for to match the `^` in strMessage.  Either way, that would fix your delimiter problem.  But either way would not fix the `%ld`.  Maybe you don't even need that part and could search for simply `"^9="`

Comment: Thanks JSF. Its been quite some time since I have seen or written C/C++ code. So thanks for your patience and replies and sorry for my late reply. Actually this code is written by someone else, which I am trying to understand. I also agree that I can simply search for "^9=" in the string. However, what was the programmers intention for the "=%ld" part is still not clear to me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Simon Kraemer. But how do I use pastebin? What is its use? Thanks

Comment: @XMarshall Sorry I forgot to finish my comment...-.- The text I posted on pastbin should be like it is in your data.

Comment: Did the original code ever work?  My best guess on seeing all this is that the original programmer was confused and tried something not even close to working and then never exercised it.